# Where does sharepoint store the "Video Rendition" info

Tags: 2013, development, publishing-site, rich-text, video

I am working on a Team Site collection inside SharePoint on-premise 2013, and i have enabled the publishing infrastructure featres. 
now i want to add a Video inside my discussion board list, so i did the following:-

1. create new Discussion board item.
2. inside the Body field, i went to "Insert" >> "Video and audio" >> "From computer". i select a video named admin.mp4

[image]

so a new video named `admin.mp4` was uploaded to the images library correctly.

3. then i wanted to upload an updated version of this video, so i repeat the same steps , where i make sure that i have checked a check box named "Add new version to existing files".
4. But now after i click on the "ok" to upload the new version of the video, the content type i will get will be "Video Rendition" instead of "Video".

[image]

And when i completed the upload process i have noticed that the original video which i have uploaded inside the images library is still on version 1, and i could not find where the new "Video Rendition" info is being stored ???

Can anyone adivce on this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Videos are treated as a kind of document set within SP -- meaning that the "video" you see in the library is actually a folder and then the renditions are kept inside that "folder."

Here is some information about [versioning document sets](https://www.sharepointeurope.com/sharepoint-2013-versioning-and-document-sets/). When new content is uploaded to a document set, the set doesn't get a new version.

In your case the folder is called `admin` and the video itself lives inside `admin/admin.mp4`. If you **Edit properties** for your admin video. then click the *This video's renditions* drop down and click the **Manage renditions** link. You will see the list of renditions inside your admin folder. If you then click the ellipsis and select **View history** you should be able to see the history of the rendition.